# Why is the population of post-Soviet states declining?

Tags: european-union, europe, ukraine, demographics, population

After the fall of the Soviet Union, many modern European states gain independence: the Baltic republics, Ukraine, Belarus.

But there is something common among nearly all of them: their populations has been declining directly from the fall of the USSR up to today:
[Latvia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Latvia), [Estonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Estonia), [Lithuania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Lithuania), [Belarus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Belarus), [Ukraine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Ukraine). The population decline in Belarus is comparatively slower, but it's still declining.

It seems strange, because most of those countries have now western economics, and are integrated into western structures: EU and WTO. What's the explanation for this?

Comment: Comments deleted. Please don't use comments to answer the question or to debate the subject matter of the question. For more information on what comments should and should not be used for, please refer to [the help article about the commenting privilege](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This question could at least have looked up some numbers and divided the problem into birth/mortality rate versus immigration/emigration.

Comment: It's simple: because the total of births + immigration is less than that of deaths + emigration!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Economic migration (temporary or more permanent) is considered the main factor. This is quite apparent in the Eastern EU countries. Note that the official EU terminology is "mobility" not migration, inside the Single Market.

[image]

([Source](https://berlinpolicyjournal.com/europe-by-numbers-the-price-of-mobility/).)

Bruegel [has](https://bruegel.org/reader/people-on-the-move#) roughly the same info as a graph over time.

[image]

Something a bit similar [happens](https://www.bloomberg.com/opinion/articles/2019-02-20/eastern-europe-feeds-on-a-shrinking-ukraine) to Ukraine's workforce, even though they're not in the EU, but in a certain partnership.

I did find some [expert opinions](https://www.euronews.com/2018/01/26/the-world-s-fastest-falling-populations-will-be-in-eastern-europe-):

> Eastern Europe is set to have all but one of the world’s fastest-shrinking populations over the coming decades, according to official estimates.
>
> The number of people in Bulgaria will tumble the quickest, says the United Nations, from 7.08 million now to 5.42m by 2050.
>
> A swathe of other eastern European countries will suffer a similar fate: from Latvia and Lithuania in the north to Romania and Moldova further south.
>
> Experts say falling fertility rates and economic emigration are combining to reduce the number of people in some eastern European countries.
>
> The fertility rate of European Union states has fallen from 2.6 births per woman in 1960 to 1.6 in 2015.
>
> Poland, whose population is predicted to fall by six million over the next three decades, had a fertility rate of 1.32 in 2015. It is one of the lowest levels in the European Union - only Portugal’s was smaller.
>
> It has prompted a rather drastic — if comic — remedy: the country's health ministry released a video urging its citizens to 'breed like rabbits'.
>
> Emigration has also played a major role in the falling populations. [...] This has especially been the case for the most-recent countries to join the EU, such as Bulgaria and Romania.
>
> Brussels-based economic think-tank Bruegel claimed in a recent report that the population of young people in Latvia and Lithuania dropped by up to 25% between 2008-2014 as a result of emigration.
>
> “Emigration is certainly a major factor,” Bernd Parusel, a migration expert with the European Migration Network told Euronews.
>
> “Especially young people tend to leave, to study or work in other EU member states or even farther abroad.

The drop in fertility itself is probably correlated to that age profile of those who leave, i.e. the older people who stay probably aren't as likely to have as many children.

If that's not convincing enough, I'll try to find some studies that actually correlate depopulation with the aforementioned processes.

---

Some IMF researchers had [a paper](https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/sdn/2016/sdn1607.pdf) on this (which I found via an article in The Economist) which apportions migration effects on population growth. Alas their data only goes up to 2012 (despite the paper being published in 2016):

> The scale of emigration from CESEE countries since the early 1990s has been
>   staggering. During the past 25 years, nearly 20 million people (5½ percent of the CESEE
>   population) are estimated to have left the region (Figure 2). By end 2012, Southeastern Europe (SEE)
>   had experienced the largest outflows, amounting to about 16 percent of the early-1990s population.
>   Emigration has also been persistent—annually, reaching as high as ½–1 percent of the 1990s
>   population—and has tended to pick up following each new wave of EU expansion in 2004 (Estonia,
>   Hungary, Latvia, Lithuania, Poland, Czech Republic, Slovak Republic and Slovenia), 2007 (Romania
>   and Bulgaria), and 2013 (Croatia). The non-EU SEE (SEE-XEU) countries have seen easing access for
>   their citizens for travel to Western Europe, and thus stay and work.
>
> Emigration significantly lowered population growth in sending countries, in some
>   cases worsening already negative demographic trends. Between 1990 and 2012, outward
>   migration from SEE shaved off more than 8 percentage points from cumulative population growth.
>   While these trends were partly offset by strong population growth in some CE-5 (CE-5 refers to the
>   Czech Republic, Hungary, Poland, Slovak Republic, and Slovenia) and SEE countries, emigration has
>   aggravated already pronounced negative demographic trends in the Baltics and some
>   Commonwealth of Independent States (CIS) countries. As a result, local populations in most
>   countries in the region have been stagnant or shrinking.
>
> [image]

Comment: Fast and good, as usual, @Fizz. Would be greatly impressed, if you touch possible origins of such amount of migration (in fact, half of Baltic states are already out).

Comment: Die Zeit has a really nice interactive EU demographics change map at municipality level! https://www.zeit.de/politik/ausland/2019-07/demographics-europe-map-cities-regions-inhabitants

Comment: Hi there! I'm from Latvia! :) I don't have any data - so just a comment from me - but the impression from ground zero here is, indeed, that this is mostly money-related. Although we do enjoy a fairly westernized lifestyle, the average wage is still fairlylow compared to other countries. Just last year it finally surpassed 1000€/month _before taxes_ - that's about 743€ after taxes. That's not a lot. Not if you want to have 2+ kids. In addition, the real estate market is also against large families. [contd.]

Comment: Something we've inherited from the Sovied Union - the majority of people live in apartment blocks. And those blocks are almost exclusively 2 or 3 room apartments. 4 room or larger apartments are RARE and consequently very expensive. Buying or building a house is equally as expensive. Surprisingly, even in new apartment blocks (there are some built here and there), most apartments seem to be 3-room apartments. And, of course, those are about twice as expensive as apartments in older blocks. So if you want a large family, you'll have a really hard time finding a big enough place to live.

Comment: @user2501323 The people would have emigrated sooner if it was possible. Post-soviet states are still much poorer and struggle to find enough capital. In some cases, the governments and/or people actively fight against foreign capital. All of this increases the benefits of moving to a richer country. If you're not strongly nationalist (or tied to your home), why wouldn't you move to a place where you get many times higher income, better services etc.? And that's before you include things like health and social benefits.

Comment: @Luaan, you are right, no doubt. I'm just impressed by that pivot on all graphs - in 1990-1991. The thing I wanted to make a point(and which was not found in answers) - does a de-industrialization make its part in de-population of those republics? How heavy states were de-industrialized before including into EU?

Comment: When comparing fertility rates in 2015, it would be more telling to compare them to early and mid 80's rather than mid 60's.  The fertility rates in the mid 60's were still effected by the cultural aftershocks of WWII (and the large reduction in the population of the reproductive-age men which it caused).

Comment: @Luaan poor countries usually see higher birth rates than wealthy ones.

Comment: @grovkin The problem is that you needed even poorer countries for that :) Basically, you get lots of births in places where kids are a net economic benefit in reasonably short-term. That usually means things like kids helping on a farm or in a shop. Many countries in Eastern Europe are stuck in the worst of it - not rich *or* poor enough to be able to afford big families, and already well on the way from the traditional "mother stays at home with kids" (so there's no "loss of income" etc.) and the communist "kids are in daycare while parents work for free" and "child labour is fine".

Comment: @grovkin And of course, post-com countries *do* have substantially larger birth rates, the poorer the higher. It's just that they also have lots of emmigration that more than offsets the higher birth rate. Plenty of people leave for better pastures.

Comment: @luaan, that's not the case.  declining birth rates is a major social issue in post-soviet countries.

Comment: @grovkin Declining birth rates *compared to previous birth rates*. Not to contemporary birth rates in the west. Eastern Block countries spent huge amounts of resources to encourage population growth (with a few exceptions like Russia that did the exact opposite), and also encouraged growth culture in general.

Answer (score 17):

*I'll preface this answer by saying that Initially I intended to gather data in support of my initial speculation: that population decline is due to economic migration. After gathering data I have decided however to keep this answer as pure data and let others provide answers based on any specific country's situation. This might be considered a "support" answer in a way.*

I have compiled following list based on [CIA World Factbook](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/resources/the-world-factbook/docs/one_page_summaries.html) (after taking USSR successor states list from wiki). List includes total population change (in percent) taken directly from factbook, natural population change (in percent) calculated as difference between births and deaths given in factbook, net migration taken directly from factbook and, included after I started compiling list, median age taken directly from factbook.

```
   Country name | total | natural | net migration | median age
1. Armenia      | -0.25 |   0.31  |     -0.56     |    35.6
2. Azerbaijan   |  0.83 |   0.83  |      0.0      |    31.7
3. Belarus      | -0.24 |  -0.32  |      0.07     |    40.3
4. Estonia      | -0.6  |  -0.28  |     -0.31     |    43
5. Georgia      |  0.01 |   0.12  |     -0.11     |    38.3
6. Kazakhstan   |  0.98 |   0.93  |      0.04     |    30.9
7. Kyrgyzstan   |  1.02 |   1.52  |     -0.51     |    26.8
8. Latvia       | -1.10 |  -0.49  |     -0.60     |    43.9
9. Lithuania    | -1.10 |  -0.50  |     -0.61     |    44.0
10. Moldova     | -1.06 |  -0.14  |     -0.93     |    37.0
11. Russia      | -0.11 |  -0.27  |      0.17     |    39.8
12. Tajikistan  |  1.58 |   1.69  |     -0.11     |    24.8
13. Turkmenistan|  1.10 |   1.28  |     -0.18     |    28.3
14. Ukraine     |  0.04 |  -0.42  |      0.46     |    40.8
15. Uzbekistan  |  0.91 |   1.12  |     -0.21     |    29.1
```

As it turns out, not all post soviet states experience negative population growth. In fact, those which do are in minority. Those are however, the most known post soviet countries: Russia, Belorussia and Baltics.

Majority of states experience negative net migration.

Ukraine is the only one to experience total increase despite negative surplus of births over deaths.

Armenia is the only one to experience population decrease despite positive surplus of births.

In countries with largest population decline, decline is caused by compounding of higher mortality rate than birth rate AND negative net migration.

Countries with largest population growth maintain population growth despite moderate to severe negative net migration.

Median age appears to be an excellent predictor for natural population growth. For reasons why some countries have lower median age, I'd like to refrain from going further than pointing at [population ageing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_ageing) and speculation in Fizz's answer.

As it turns out, this answer became a frame challenge answer. As for the reasons why any specific country from above list has median age it has or net migration it has, I'll leave that to other answers.

Comment: Thank you very much, looks better. Answer is good, - I've never heard about CIA factbook. But, really, the question was WHY. And, again, I don't think, that median age describes everything. Why, then, during USSR all those republics grow? What was the origin of those graph change in 1991? That was the question.

Comment: @user2501323 Did you forget that people weren't allowed to emmigrate under soviet rule? Even within the Eastern Block, moving to a different country was difficult - leaving for the much more prosperous west was outright illegal, and often meant serious trouble for the family you left behind. Borders were guarded by armed rangers who often shot on sight. A lot of people also assumed that the capitalist west is even *poorer* than the Eastern Block.

Comment: Your group of all Ex-USSR countries is a quite different group of the eastern European ex-communist countries that Fizz’ answer focuses most on, the only overlap being Estonia, Latvia and Lithuania (and to a lesser extent Belarus, Moldova and Ukraine). By coincidence, the overlap group is the one presented in the question. Don’t know what to make of it, I’ll leave it here.

Answer (score 11):

I think that the other answers miss the main point, which is not migration away from the country, but rather the lack of migration into the country. The population is decreasing practically everywhere in the western world, but in more developed countries the (economic) immigration makes up for this loss and keeps the population stable.

Comment: Well, even refugees don't want to go to Romania. https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/8gkvjp/afghan-refugees-in-romania-crying-not-hungary-876 They prefer Germany. So it's not like Romania can attract some flow that would not go to Germany once in... The whole fence thing that Hungary put up is because refugees wanted to pass *through* Hungary to greener pastures further West.

Comment: Romania did get some refugees eventually, and gave them asylum. But they pay very little money (~100 euros a month) as assistance. https://www.euractiv.ro/the-uncountried-romania/refugee-in-romania-i-left-to-avoid-being-killed.-my-family-sold-everything-and-all-the-money-went-to-the-smugglers.-7002  So the same economic disincentives still apply. Also it seems that the refugees they got were still trying to get to the West, bypassing the Hungarian fence. https://www.pri.org/stories/2017-09-26/romania-faces-new-rush-migrant-boats-smugglers-test-new-routes-europe

Comment: There is significant migration into Russia. Without it the drop would be much worse. It is significantly changing the demographics of some regions (togetjer with higher natality in Caucasus).

Answer (score 10):

*Almost all* European countries have below-replacement birth rates - that is, less than 2 births per woman on average, assuming approximately equal numbers of each gender.

This follows an ongoing trend from the start of effective medical treatment, and particularly from the start of vaccination. When most children died before the age of 5, you had to have lots of children in order for some to have families themselves. When most children survived, you no longer had to pay the odds this way. The modem approach to child-rearing then took over, where with fewer children to take care of, parents could invest more heavily per child to give their children the best possible start. Quality over quantity, in other words.

It took time for this idea to take hold though, and the early-1800s jump in population growth is remarkable, as most children now survived. The result of course was a Malthusian crisis, and crop failures such as the Irish potato blight caused major starvation until newer farming and distribution methods allowed food supplies to catch up. The current slow decline of population in the West is actually a rebalancing towards original population levels, after this boom. Other countries around the world are on their own journeys through this demographic.

Note that the exceptions to this are places where religious rules mean contraception is not widely available. The West has almost universally taken this onboard in spite of opposition from the Catholic Church, but the malign influence of the Church's policy continues to poison attempts to normalise birth rates in poorer countries around the world.

Comment: "malign influence of the Church's policy continues to poison attempts" sounds a little harsh.

Comment: The replacement rate is 2 births per woman only if the life expectancy stays constant.  Until recently, the life expectancy in the US used to go up, so the replacement rate was slightly lower.  Although it did mean an aging population.

Comment: @domotorp But true - that is the official Catholic church policy. The only matter of opinion is whether it's "malign". Since the UN formally recognises access to contraception as a human right, then the Catholic Church is by definition opposing human rights. I'd be genuinely interested in the reasoning for anyone who can call active opposition to human rights anything but malign.

Comment: The countries with the highest birth rates do not have a majority Catholic population: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_and_dependent_territories_by_birth_rate.

Comment: @grovkin True in the short term, but in the long term we all die. A cheery thought for your Tuesday. ;)

Comment: @Graham, it's not about any one person though.  Life expectancy grew at a rate faster than 1 year per year for a while.

Comment: @grovkin Only if you include women who failed to reach adulthood, which isn't usually done. If you account for premature deaths, the replacement rate is usually around 2.1 children per woman in the west. But that's pointless quibble anyway, given that most countries still expect exponential growth rather than a stable population or outright decline. It seems to be surprisingly hard to grasp that no matter how small the growth, it's still growth.

Comment: @grovkin, `The replacement rate is 2 births per woman` — shouldn't it be `2 birth per couple`? Because if a woman has two children from two different fathers you now have 3 people of previous generation and 2 on new one.

Comment: @user28434 But of the two birth only one will be a girl to grow up to become a woman.

Comment: @user28434 i was using the same language as what i replied to, but it still makes sense because roughly half of the population are women.

Comment: @James Kind of true, but irrelevant.  Like I said, the prerequisite is a stable society with good healthcare, which countries at the top of the list clearly do not have.

Comment: At least in Germany but I believe all across western capitalist countries the most significant decline in birth rate was what Germans know as *Pillenknick* (literally the pill kink) in the mid-60’s where a cheap, easy and effective method of contraception (the hormone pill) became available.

Comment: @Jan Yes, that was certainly a factor.  But according to https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/birthsdeathsandmarriages/conceptionandfertilityrates/bulletins/childbearingforwomenbornindifferentyearsenglandandwales/2015-11-10 the average family was already down to 2 point something children by 1920, at least in the UK.  The change due to the Pill may be visible in the data, but this isn't the biggest change from a pre-industrial baseline of women typically giving birth (or miscarrying) every couple of years.

Comment: @Graham After looking at [older data for Germany](http://www.bpb.de/politik/grundfragen/deutsche-verhaeltnisse-eine-sozialkunde/138003/historischer-rueckblick?p=all) (scroll down to the graph) it seems your right; the First World War brought the birth rate down, it recovered briefly in 1920 (when the soldiers came home) but stayed around 2 children per woman until the late 60’s.

Comment: @Jan Thanks - that's a nice graph which goes back further.  Even so, it only starts at 1870 when healthcare was already getting pretty good.  If we had numbers for the 1300s then I'm sure those numbers would be a lot higher, as they are in parts of Africa which are still lacking proper healthcare.  We certainly have data for royal families going back to that era which shows their childbirth and child mortality rates.

Comment: Why any mention of Malthus? The Great Famine was not Malthusian: the problem was not population outstripping production but the sudden failure of production from blight, exacerbating the hardships for an already impoverished population. England saw similar growth rates but no Malthusian catastrophe.

Comment: "The current slow decline of population in the West is actually a rebalancing towards original population levels, after this boom." The West is still increasing in population. The Anglosphere definitely is and immigration is currently offsetting population decline in Western Europe. Latin America, if you consider it part of the West, is still growing as well. The countries that are actually undergoing population decline are the post-Soviet states, Portugal, Greece, Japan, Italy, and Nauru, most of which aren't part of the West.

Comment: @gormadoc It was very much Malthusian. The Irish tradition of land ownership was that it was divided amongst the children. Over generations, that left families with not enough land to feed themselves. The potato propped up those families to just about keep them afloat - until the day the blight hit and it didn't. England had different land ownership traditions and more of a spread of farming which meant they didn't get bitten in quite the same way. And of course England had alternative employment in the cities, which Ireland never did. Add absentee landlords too, for extra crapness.

Comment: Malthus posited that population growth would outstrip food production, absent other factors like disease or war.  What you're talking about is simply a famine and Malthus himself would have considered that nature's way of avoiding a catastrophe. A Malthusian catastrophe does not include triggers other than population growth; including falling production would make virtually all deaths due to hunger Malthusian.

Comment: @gormadoc Like I said, population growth had far outstripped production with all previous crops.  The discovery of the "Lumper" potato variety barely allowed food production at just-above-starvation levels, on a good year - and the population kept on rising.  The ***definition*** of a "Malthusian catastrophe" is that the poor are vulnerable to famine (and other foreseeable shortages) due to over-population; it is not an shortfall of production versus consumption in a good year. Deaths from famine contributed to by overpopulation ***are*** Malthusian, by Malthus's own definition.

Comment: The problem is that you're assigning the cause of the Great Famine to over-population rather than the more clear causes: potato blight and bad management. Under Malthus' theory, the population growth rate would have fallen and stabilized over time to adjust to the resource availability. Indeed, the growth rate started falling just after he published the 1826 edition. There's no indication that the island was over-populated and couldn't have continued growing absent the blight. You see a symptom and assume the cause is something other than the obvious. Was the Holodomor Malthusian?

Comment: @gormadoc And population growth did fall and stabilise. Malthus's theory wasn't that the reduction would be continuous - he was quite clear that the issue was vulnerability to one or two bad years, and that's exactly how it happened. As for evidence that farms could not sustain families, it's simple historical fact. Try https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_farm_subdivision for a quick version.

Answer (score 2):

CSIS's "Russian Roulette" podcast covered it in [Episode 38: "Of Post-Soviet Demographics"](https://www.csis.org/podcasts/russian-roulette/post-soviet-demographics-russian-roulette-episode-38). The episode material was largely based on research by political scientist [Judy Twigg](https://politicalscience.vcu.edu/people/faculty/twigg.html).

There are three main drivers (A good article detailing them is ["Russia’s Fraught Demographic Future" by Ilan Berman](https://jamestown.org/program/ilan-berman-russias-fraught-demographic-future/):

- **Mortality**

  > According to UN estimates, Russia now ranks 126th in the world, with an average life expectancy for its citizens just below 70 years of age, on par with North Korea (average life expectancy: 69.91) and behind Tonga (average life expectancy: 72.6). (*Source: Wiki*)
- **Abortion rates**

  > If this tally is accurate, then the true cost of Russia’s abortion culture is the annual termination of **more than 1 percent of the country’s total population**.
- **Emigration**, for political and/or economic reasons

  From Judy Twigg's [2016 "Russia Is Losing Its Best and Brightest"](https://nationalinterest.org/feature/russia-losing-its-best-brightest-16572):

  > Russian government statistics show a sharp upturn in emigration over the last four years. Almost 123,000 officially departed in 2012, rising to 186,000 in 2013, and accelerating to almost 309,000 in 2014 after the annexation of Crimea and even more in 2015. These statistics probably underestimate actual flows, however, as many people no longer notify the government that they’re leaving.

While this focuses on Russia proper, many of the same factors apply to entire post-soviet space, to one degree or another.

Comment: Interesting, but you can't discount collapsing birth rates which have all but become a cultural phenomenon.

Comment: Somehow I doubt the abortion rates account for the fact that the same woman might have an abortion multiple times in the time it would take her to deliver a baby, recover from that and have another baby. So it might be true that there are as many abortions as 1% of the population, but the implication that this means another -1% to population growth is misleading at best.

Comment: Abortion ("abortion culture", seriously?) is not a cause of low births, it's a consequence of poor access to contraception. 30% of the population are below the poverty line, abortion is covered by insurance, contraception isn't.